# gvim8.1 :term CreateProcess failed

Tags: vim

Recently I run into a problem with my gVim's 8.1 `:terminal` command that I can't figure out. 
When I type `:term` or `:terminal` in gVim 8.1 I keep getting this message saying

> CreateProcess failed

I looked it up on the internet but I couldn't find anything specific. Also, FZF stopped opening the files on pressing Enter, and I was thinking that these things may be related.

I should mention that prior to this errors happening I was trying to install ZSH and OH-MY-ZSH, without any success though :), I was trying to make them work with CygWin and then I deleted everything(CygWin, ZSH, OH-MY-ZSH) since I wasn't getting anywhere.

Anywho, I just mentioned this cause maybe they're related.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbZNG.png

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the answer to the question I posted about 20 min ago. :)).
I just had to remove SHELL - /bin/zsh environment variable from the System Environment.